# Max Argument/Parameter in a JS function

Tags: javascript

Sorry to ask this question. Just for general Knowledge purpose. 
What is the maximum number of (argument/parameter) can be sent inside Javascript function?

Comment: _theoretically_ there is not a maximun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ECMAScript 5.1](http://es5.github.io/#x8.8)

> The List type is used to explain the evaluation of argument lists (see
>   11.2.4) in new expressions, in function calls, and in other algorithms where a simple list of values is needed. Values of the List type are
>   simply ordered sequences of values. These sequences may be of any
>   length.

Theoretically there is not a maximun, but your memory is not infinite. so in practice, is limited.

You can read some experiments in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22747272/1539655)