# how to avoid stack overflow when applying max to a large array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

The following code

```
var interval = function (a, b) {
          var i, list = [];
          for (i = a; i <= b; i++) {
            list.push(i);
          }
          return list;
        },
    xs = interval(1, 500000);

Math.max.apply(null, xs);
```

generates an Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
How to overcome?

Note that the interval function is just a quick way to generate test data.

I used the Math.max.apply method because it is described here: [Mozilla developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

This is not an acceptable solution because javascript has a maximum number of arguments allowed for a function call, thanks to Rocket Hazmat for pointing it out, see his answer for more informations.

The underscore.js library uses a simple implementation for the max function, and I believe that the most appropriate solution is to include a simple max implementation in the codebase and use it. See @AnotherDev answer for more details

Comment: lol - avoid "stack overflow" by solving your own problems :D

Comment: You could simply compute the max while generating the list, or by iterating through the values. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747068/is-there-a-max-number-of-arguments-javascript-functions-can-accept

Comment: P.S. Don't you know the max value already?  You're calling `interval` with 2 numbers.  Clearly, `b` (500000) is the biggest.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, the interval there doesn't matter, it is just a way to demonstrate the concept, building fake data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is with the line:

```
Math.max.apply(null, xs);
```

You are trying to call `Math.max(1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 500000);`.  JavaScript doesn't like calling a function with 500,000 parameters.

See this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22747272

Comment: thanks @Rocket Hazmat, this seems the most appropriate answer

Answer (score 3):

If you want a work around, you can use underscore.js

From the [source code](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L304-L327), it looks like they just loop through the elements using a for loop

```
for (var i = 0, length = obj.length; i < length; i++) {
        value = obj[i];
        if (value > result) {
          result = value;
        }
      }
```

[Here is an example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yafhjmzn/)

```
var interval = function (a, b) {
          var i, list = [];
          for (i = a; i <= b; i++) {
            list.push(i);
          }
          return list;
        },
    xs = interval(1, 500000);

console.log(_.max(xs))
//prints 500000
```

Comment: Thanks @AnotherDev, I looked in underscore sources too and reached the same conclusion, calling Math.max.apply on a large array is not allowed, the best approach is to have a max() implementation in the codebase