# Javascript for/in loop - join items from two different objects?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach, for-in-loop

I have these datasets below and I want to joint the data in each set:

```
    var data = {};
    var datasets = [
        {"_id":"58d6c806d7c80d5d44a35204","particles":{"timestamp":[1490470918708,1490470962915,1490470967186],"Particles":["108","108","109"]}},
        {"_id":"58d6caf62552b75f26f56f91","particles":{"timestamp":[1490471670888,1490473309103],"Particles":["109","100"]}}
    ];

    datasets.forEach(function(dataset, index) {
        for (var key in dataset.particles) {
            data[key] = dataset.particles[key];
        }
    });
    console.log(data);
```

Result:

```
{ timestamp: [ 1490471670888, 1490473309103 ],
  Particles: [ '109', '100' ] }
```

They are not joined. The result I am after:

```
 { timestamp: [ 1490470918708,1490470962915,1490470967186, 1490471670888, 1490473309103 ],
  Particles: [ '108','108','109', '109', '100' ] }
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Is `concat` or `push` faster when comes to a very **large** data?

Comment: As I see a lot of good answer so I am not going to write mine. Just a comment I notices a lot of people are using `concat`. This creates a new array every time instead of just appending new items in the existing array. I recommend using `push` instead.

Comment: @Luka is push faster than concat?

Comment: In general `push` is faster if you call it with `Array.prototype.push.apply`. But be careful as this way has limit: you cannot append large amount of items this way.

Comment: @Luka i need to push very large amount of data. so I think concat is better then?

Comment: then use concat to be on the safe side. Using `push` may simply break the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to concatanate the arrays, not just reassign the value.

```js
var data = {};
var datasets = [
    {"_id":"58d6c806d7c80d5d44a35204","particles":{"timestamp":[1490470918708,1490470962915,1490470967186],"Particles":["108","108","109"]}},
    {"_id":"58d6caf62552b75f26f56f91","particles":{"timestamp":[1490471670888,1490473309103],"Particles":["109","100"]}}
];

datasets.forEach(function(dataset, index) {
  for (var key in dataset.particles) {

    // Check if key already exists.
    if( data[key] === undefined )
      data[key] = [];

    // Add current timestamps.
    data[key] = data[key].concat(dataset.particles[key]);
  }
});
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what required :

```js
var data = {};
var datasets = [{
    "_id": "58d6c806d7c80d5d44a35204",
    "particles": {
      "timestamp": [1490470918708, 1490470962915, 1490470967186],
      "Particles": ["108", "108", "109"]
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "58d6caf62552b75f26f56f91",
    "particles": {
      "timestamp": [1490471670888, 1490473309103],
      "Particles": ["109", "100"]
    }
  }
];
var output = {

}
datasets.forEach(function(dataset, index) {
  for (var key in dataset.particles) {
    if (typeof output[key] == 'undefined') {
      output[key] = []
    }
    //console.log(dataset.particles[key])
    for (var k of dataset.particles[key]) {
      output[key].push(k)
    }

  }
});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! is concat or push **faster** when comes to a very large data?

Comment: seems like concat is much faster then push
checkout the difference from here https://jsperf.com/concat-vs-push-array/1

Answer (score 1):

In a *functional programming* style, you could use `reduce` and `Object.keys`:

```js
var datasets = [
    {"_id":"58d6c806d7c80d5d44a35204","particles":{"timestamp":[1490470918708,1490470962915,1490470967186],"Particles":["108","108","109"]}},
    {"_id":"58d6caf62552b75f26f56f91","particles":{"timestamp":[1490471670888,1490473309103],"Particles":["109","100"]}}
];

var data = datasets.reduce ( (acc, {particles}) =>
    Object.keys(particles).reduce ( (acc, key) =>
        (acc[key] = (acc[key] || []).concat(particles[key]), acc), acc
), {} );
    
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Alternative with `push` instead of `concat`, in case performance is an issue:

```js
var datasets = [
    {"_id":"58d6c806d7c80d5d44a35204","particles":{"timestamp":[1490470918708,1490470962915,1490470967186],"Particles":["108","108","109"]}},
    {"_id":"58d6caf62552b75f26f56f91","particles":{"timestamp":[1490471670888,1490473309103],"Particles":["109","100"]}}
];

var data = datasets.reduce ( (acc, {particles}) =>
    Object.keys(particles).reduce ( (acc, key) =>
        ((acc[key] = (acc[key] || [])).push(...particles[key]), acc), acc
), {} );
    
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

But be aware that in this version of the code, `push` will get each individual array element in `particles[key]` as an argument, which occupies stack space, which in turn is limited. See ["Is there a max number of arguments JavaScript functions can accept?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22747068/5459839). You could overcome this limitation, by performing separate `push` calls for each individual element in `particles[key]`, but that will degrade performance. So in the end you could be better of with the `concat` version.

Comment: thanks. is this faster than for loop for concatenating very large data?

Comment: Why not test it on your data? In general `for` loops are fast, but if you do a lot of manipulation inside those loops, then array methods can sometimes lead to code with fewer assignments, which can then be better optimised by the engine. It all depends on your actual case and data. Just test it.

Comment: I added a variant with `push` instead of `concat`, but it really is to be tested whether there is a performance difference for your case.