# Failed to construct 'Blob': Array length exceeds supported limit

Tags: javascript

I try to construct a simple 10.5mb [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) using the following (Chrome browser):

```
var arr = new Uint8Array(10485833);
var blob = new Blob(arr, { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
```

I get the error:

> Uncaught RangeError: Failed to construct 'Blob': Array length exceeds supported limit.

What is the limit? Why can't I create a 10mb blob? What if I wanted to create a 50mb blob? 1gb blob?

Is [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) the wrong data type to be using here? In the end I am trying to construct some [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to post to a server. Example:

```
var fd = new FormData();
var blob = new Blob(arr, { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
fd.append('data', blob, 'filename.zip');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because Blob expects an array of chunks. 
The array you are passing is way too big for it. ([Probably related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747068/is-there-a-max-number-of-arguments-javascript-functions-can-accept))

The solution is simply to wrap this array in a single lenghted array.

```js
var arr = new Uint8Array(10485833);
console.log(new Blob([ arr ], {type:'application/octet-stream'}))
//                   ^_____^_____ wrapped in a single lengthed Array
```