# Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in HTML2Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

How can i solve this problem ?

```
function flatten(arrays) {
    return [].concat.apply([], arrays);
}
```

```
Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at flatten (html2canvas.js:2650)
at new NodeParser (html2canvas.js:1861)
at renderWindow (html2canvas.js:1019)
at html2canvas.js:1006
at <anonymous>
```

Please help

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747068/is-there-a-max-number-of-arguments-javascript-functions-can-accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably passed a large number of arrays into the function. You can try something like this instead:

```
function flatten(arrays){
    return arrays.reduce(function(prev, curr){
        return prev.concat(curr);
    }, []);
}

var matrix = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4]
];
flatten(matrix);    // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: That's a good idea, but since the error is raised in html2canvas.js:2650, I think OP should rather raise an issue on the [github's project](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas).

Comment: The `flatten` function actually comes from some other sources (probably from Babel), so I'm not sure where the bug should be reported to.

Comment: I tried this code on html2canvas.js. There's no error, but its not rendering either. I tried to add a 'log()' on 'function flatten' it becomes infinite loop. My pages has 40,000 pixel height and there's so many elements to render.The version of  html2canvas is 0.5.0-beta4

Comment: @Kel It's probably taking a very long time to concatenate all the rows given that you had so many rows (>65536).

Comment: even if i added the "type : 'view' " in the html2canvas ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library, but since it exceeded the max stack size, I would assume the matrix has way too many rows in it.

Comment: Thanks!! I tried to wait for it. Its all good now. It renders the whole page then cut it down on what the user can see in the viewport. Thats why its too slow.

Comment: There might be ways to speed it up by not using `.concat`, but I prefer to leave the optimization for the developer himself.