# Multi-dimensional arrays and how to find largest number

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to find and return the largest number in each array using a for loop but every time I try to print something I get an error. I have tried using the following JS array methods: Math.max, Math.max.apply but I cannot get them to work.

My code is below. Any help will be appreciated and if you could please point out what I am doing wrong, that would be really great. Thanks in advance!

Question: numbers is an array of integers.  Find and return the largest integer.

My code:

```
function largestNumber(numbers) { // this function was given by the quiz writer, my code starts below "code here"
  // code here

  numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  for(let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    let largest = 0;
    if(numbers[i] > largest){
      largest = largest.numbers[i];
    }
  }
  return largest;
}

console.log(largestNumber);
```

Comment: you are setting `largest` back to 0 on every iteration of the loop. Put the declaration of `largest` outside of your for loop.

Comment: Also, I think you meant to write `largest = numbers[i];`

Comment: *"Multi-dimensional arrays... in **each** array"* - The code shown processes one single-dimensional array. Should the `numbers` argument actually allow for multi-dimensional arrays, or...? Also `console.log(largestNumber);` doesn't *call* your function, you'd need `console.log(largestNumber());`, or really you should be passing the numbers in as an argument, so `largestNumber([1,2,3,4])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Math.max.apply` as below sample to find max value in array

```js
function largestNumber(numbers) {
    return Math.max.apply(null, numbers);
}
console.log(largestNumber([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Comment: It's noteworthy to mention the new and cleaner syntax for the same operation. `Math.max(...numbers)`

Comment: But be careful, exist practical limit to count of arguments passed to function in [different browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22747272/3047033)