# Zip arrays as keys and values of an Object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this data

```
 var foo = ['US','MX','NZ'];
 var foo1 = [12',13',17];


 var Object = {};
```

Ive tried this thing

```
 var Object = {foo:foo1}
```

but it is not working
when i arrayed the object using alert (JSON.stringify(Object)); i saw:

```
 {"foo":["12","13","17"]}
```

what I want is that make it like this:

```
var Object = {
  "US":"12",
  "MX":"13",
  "NZ":17
}
```

is there any  way I could make it looked like this?

Comment: This function is called "zip". The difficult part of solving a problem is not knowing what words to look for :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create an object from an array of keys and an array of values](/q/39127989/90527)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iterate over any one array using [**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and use the `index` to retrieve the element from second array.Also note the usage of square `[]`  braces & the variable is named as obj(it can be anything) but avoided `Object`

```js
var foo = ['US', 'MX', 'NZ'];
var foo1 = [12, '13', 17];


var obj = {};
foo.forEach(function(item, index) {
  obj[item] = foo1[index]

});
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: yep! your'e the first one still waiting for 6 minutes to mark it! thanks again brother!

Answer (score 15):

You could map the objects for a single object with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
var keys = ['US', 'MX', 'NZ'],
    values = ['12', '13', '17'],
    object = Object.assign(...keys.map((k, i) => ({ [k]: values[i] })));

console.log(object);
```

A newer approach with [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
var keys = ['US', 'MX', 'NZ'],
    values = ['12', '13', '17'],
    object = Object.fromEntries(keys.map((k, i) => [k, values[i]]));

console.log(object);
```

Comment: Hum. I guess that this answer should be considered as the best henceforth. Why not otherwise (?)

Comment: It works for the question as asked, but isn't generically applicable.
With a large number of keys the spread operator could exceed the JS engine's argument length limit. That should be in the 10s of thousands though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22747272/322333

Comment: the first solution doesnt work in Typescript `A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.` You have to pass in the first parameter like so `Object.assign({}, ...keys.map((k, i) => ({ [k]: values[i] })));`

Comment: @Xitcod13, this answer is in javascript. for typescript, it could be different.

Comment: It's not really a critique of the answer I just posting it here for people that come  in the future. It can be hard to figure this stuff out when it's not really obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
     let keys = ['US','MX','NZ'],
     values = [12,13,17], 
     myObject = {};
     for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) myObject[keys[i]] = values[i];
```

```js
     let keys = ['US','MX','NZ'],
     values = [12,13,17], 
     myObject = {};
     for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) myObject[keys[i]] = values[i];
    

     console.log(myObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const keys = ['name', 'age'];
const vals = ['anna', 20];

keys.reduce((o, e, i) => ((o[e] = vals[i]), o), {});
// {name: 'anna', age: 20}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: @Boy: is it possible to get some insight into what the callback function body is doing here? I assume the `o` is added after the assignment expression to act as the return value, but I'm not familiar with the syntax. My understanding from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#syntax) is that arrow functions must use `{` `}` when they contain statements rather than a single expression, but it looks like you are using statements `((o[e] = vals[i]), o)` and it works. Do you know where this behaviour is described (or anyone else)?

Answer (score 0):

Boy's answer is very concise, but it took me a bit to figure out why it worked. Here's an explanation with some tweaks.

```
const keys = ['name', 'age'];
const vals = ['anna', 20];

keys.reduce((newArray, key, index) => ((newArray[key] = vals[index]), newArray), {});
```

Setting `{}` as the last parameter of the reduce function creates a new array that is used as the initial value. Every subsequent iteration has the `newArray` passed to it as the previous value. If this wasn't specified, then each iteration would produce a different array with only one `key:value` pair.

```
newArray: {}
key: name
index: 0
values[index]: anna
* ---------------------- *
newArray: {"name":"anna"}
key: age
index: 1
values[index]: 20
* ---------------------- *
{ name: 'anna', age: 20 }
```