# What is the difference between Array.from() and Array.apply()?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I got `"Maximum call stack size exceeded."` error when using `Array.apply()` to convert a large `Uint8Array` to an `Array`.

I found that `apply()` passes my parameter array as arguments in Array's constructor and function's arguments are stored in stack. Therefore, if I pass a large array to `apply()`, it'll exceed the stack.

After some searching, I changed to use `Array.from()` and it solved my issue.

I read the algorithm in [ECMAScript](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.from) but I can't understand it. So, could someone tell me the difference between `apply()` and `from()`?

Comment: Not sure if this is a duplicate of that question. This question is asking about the difference between these two, which is not what the other question is asking, nor is it addressed in any of the answers

Comment: Do you also get an error if you do `Array(...yourArray)` ? Or maybe that doesn't work with typed arrays.

Comment: @FelixKling You mean something like this `Array(new Uint8Array(data))`. It can run without error but it just created an array that has 1 Uint8Array element. Btw, I got the answer below, thank you.

Comment: No, I really meant `Array(...data)`.... using argument spread, the modern alternative to `.apply`. But given the explanation it should result in the same issue.

Comment: @FelixKling I tried using argument spread and it still caused the error `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array.apply` calls `Function.prototype.apply` with a calling context (a `this` value) of `Array`. If the second parameter is an array-like object, it will call the Array constructor with all of the elements of that array-like object as arguments. Eg:

```
Array.apply(null, [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

results in, and is equivalent to

```
Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

But argument lists have a [size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22747068). It depends on the engine, but it looks like you probably shouldn't try to pass more than 10,000 arguments or so.

In contrast, `Array.from` invokes the iterator of the array-like object. If the iterator doesn't exist, but the object has a `length` property, it will iterate from 0 up to the value of the `length` - 1 and create an array from those values. Here, since a Uint8Array [has an iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/@@iterator), that iterator is what gets invoked when you use `Array.from`.

Iterators don't have the same sort of size limit that argument lists have (unless they're spread into an argument list, or something similar). The iterator's `.next` method is called, returning a value to put into the array, until the iterator is exhausted. It's pretty similar to the following:

```js
const arr = [0, 1, 2];

// Create a new array by iterating through arr's iterator
// just like Array.from is doing:
const newArr = [];
const iterator = arr[Symbol.iterator]();
let iterObj = iterator.next();
while (!iterObj.done) {
  newArr.push(iterObj.value);
  iterObj = iterator.next(); 
}
console.log(newArr);
```

There are no limits on how long the iterator may be, either in the above code, or in `Array.from`.

So, if the iterable or array-like object you have is very large, constructing an array from it with `Array.apply` (or by spreading into the Array constructor) may throw an error, whereas using `Array.from` will not.