# "Difference between concat() and push() methods in JavaScript arrays and when to use each?"

Tags: javascript

Question:
I'm working with arrays of objects in JavaScript and exploring methods to add new elements. I've encountered the push() and concat() methods, both of which seem to be used for adding elements to an array. However, I'm not entirely clear on the main difference between these two methods.

Here are the examples I've tried:

Example 1 (using push()):

```js
let people = [
  { name: "John", age: [30, 40], city: "New York" },
  { name: "Alice", age: [30, 40], city: "Los Angeles" },
  { name: "Bob", age: [30, 40], city: "Chicago" },
  { name: "Eva", age: [30, 60], city: "San Francisco" },
  { name: "David", age: [30, 50], city: "Miami" }
];

// Create a new person object
const newPerson = { name: "Frank", age: [25, 35], city: "Seattle" };

// Add the new person to the 'people' array using push()
people.push(newPerson);

console.log(people);
```

Example 2 (using concat()):

```js
let people = [
  { name: "John", age: [30, 40], city: "New York" },
  { name: "Alice", age: [30, 40], city: "Los Angeles" },
  { name: "Bob", age: [30, 40], city: "Chicago" },
  { name: "Eva", age: [30, 60], city: "San Francisco" },
  { name: "David", age: [30, 50], city: "Miami" }
];

const newPerson = { name: "Frank", age: [25, 35], city: "Seattle" };

people = people.concat(newPerson);

console.log(people);
```

Could someone please clarify the primary distinction between push() and concat() when it comes to adding elements to an array in JavaScript?

Comment: [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) merges two arrays and returns a new array, while [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is used for one or more individual elements and modifies the original.

Answer (score 1):

These are the differences:

- `push()` modifies the original array. `concat()` doesn't modify the original array, it returns a new array by making a shallow copy of the original array.
- If the argument to `concat()` is an array, it's merged with the original array (like `[...arr1, ...arr2]`). `push()` always adds the argument as a single element -- if it's an array, it becomes a nested array. E.g. compare `arr1.concat(arr2)` with `arr1.push(arr2)`.
- `push()` returns the length of the updated array, `concat()` returns the new array.

Comment: "`push()` always adds each of its arguments as a single element" perhaps? Related to using `push.apply` to append one array to another in-place: [Is there a max number of arguments JavaScript functions can accept?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22747068/5217142)

Comment: @traktor I'm simplifying by not mentioning multiple arguments. But for both functions, all the arguments are processed similarly. `push()` adds each, `concat()` either adds or merges each, depending on whether it's an array or not.